# Unable to cv2.imwrite in django static folder from django views

Tags: python, django, opencv, static

I am unable to save the image in `static` but can save in the same rekognition directory. How do I save a snapshot from camera to static folder?

My OpenCV code is running in post method of `views.py`.

In `views.py`:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, img = cap.read()  # Read the image from webcam
cv2.imwrite('static/video_snapshot.jpg', img)
```

[image: Tree of the directory]

Comment: OK, so what's your question? You seem to have forgotten to ask one.

Comment: Um...How do I save a snapshot from camera to static folder. My opencv code is running in post method of views.py.  The snippet of code is as shown above.

Comment: Permissions issue perhaps? Try to write a simple text file using pure Python. That may allow you to get more detailed error info, since `imwrite` is rather terse in that regard (just returns a boolean signifying success/failure).

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code in your views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
def mydata(request):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, img = cap.read()
    with open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, f'img.jpg'), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img)
    return render(request, "web.html", None)
```

Also in your settngs.py add this line

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Hoping It s helpful for you.